# Python-Requests How do I capture a specific section of html code from response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

how do I request a specific tag? For example, I want to get the footer as an output instead of the whole HTML page. how do I do that?

```py
import requests as req
    
resp = req.get("site")    
print(resp.text)
```

I want to get only this as the output instead of the whole HTML file; is it possible?

```html
<footer class="footer">
    <ol>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about_us.html"> About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="ticket.html"> Submit a ticket</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="tos.html"> Terms of use</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="donate.html"> Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="news.html"> News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="quotes.html"> Quotes</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</footer>
```

Comment: You'll likely want to use a module specifically designed for scraping/parsing html like beautifulsoup, selenium, scrapy, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ([requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/)) instead of requests. Here you can extract specific classes from a html page.

This should work:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('http://ilyabr.com')
print( r.html.find('.footer', first=True).html )
```